# How to prove that this equation is $\geq 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$\frac{(2n+2)! - (2n)!(n+1)^2}{((n+1)!)^2} + \frac{4^n \sqrt{4n+4} - 4^{n+1}\sqrt{4n}}{\sqrt{4n+4}\sqrt{4n}} \geq 0$$

This equation arose when I wanted to prove that a function was always increasing for natural numbers.** So I took a forward difference quotient and I got this equation. Can anyone prove this ?

The original equation is $$\binom{2n}{n} - \frac{4^{n}}{\sqrt{4n}}$$, so if anyone can find a way to prove that this is always increasing, then that would be fine as well.

Comment: This looks messy; I suspect that there will be an easier way to prove that your original sequence is increasing.

Comment: @mathlove messed up typing the equation, check again now

Comment: @GregMartin updated with original sequence